# $X_n \to_p X$, $g(\cdot)$ discontinuous at points with positive probability, when $g(X_n) \to_p g(X)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose $X_n$, $n = 1,2,...$ is a sequence of random variables which stochastically converge to a random variable $X \in \mathcal{X}$ . Suppose $g(\cdot)$ is discontinuous at $x_0 \in \mathcal{X}$ (e.g. $sgn(x)$ and $x_0 = 0$) and that $P(g(X) = x_0) > 0$. Is there any mode of stochastic convergence of $X_n$ to $X$ which implies $g(X_n) \to_p g(X)$ (e.g. sup convergence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_n=\frac 1 n, X=0$ then $X_n \to X$ in every conceivable  type of  convergence but the conlusion fails as soon as $g$ has  a jump at $0$.